# Plotting based on Radio Buttons in R Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
               c("Sepal.Length" = "Length",
                 "Sepal.Width" = "Width",
                 "Petal.Length" = "Length")),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length),
                   "Width" = plot(iris$Sepal.Width),
                   "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length))

    plot(dist)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I would like to have a `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` plot for each button. How can I do this?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to plot the assigned function, since `switch`it0s already doing that.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  switch(input$dist,
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length),
               "Width" = plot(iris$Sepal.Width),
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length))
           })
}
```

EDIT: Regarding using par `(mfrow=c(1,2))` and despite my comment of other alternatives, this is the alternative I came up with:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  switch(input$dist,
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length),
               "Width" = plot(iris$Sepal.Width),
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length))
  switch(input$dist,
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length),
               "Width" = plot(iris$Sepal.Width),
               "Length" = plot(iris$Sepal.Length))
       })
```

Comment: How can I have 2 plots for each button using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`?

Comment: I don't know what you want to accomplish. ¿Two plots for each button? but you are defining just one plot on ´server´. To make two plots for option I can think of two alternatives: 1) add another ´plotOutput´ in the UI rendering another plot in the server. 2) use ´ggplot´ and use ´facet´ to replicate according to a variable.

Comment: Thanks @David Jorquera, I will try with ggplot.